# How to set 2 change effects to affect on 1 select

Tags: jquery

I have 3 selects. When value on first is 2, then third select is disabled. When value of second select is 3 then third select is disabled.

This is jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/UEpQn/1/

My problem: I would like to insert mine 2 jQuery functions inside one jQuery function, which would react on either

```
$('.one').trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('.two').trigger('change');
```

I would like to do it this way because when i set first select to two and second select to three third select is disabled, but then when I change value of first select from 2, third select is enabled(and second select is still 3). This is because of the use of  $('.one').trigger('change').

**EDIT: Corrected bad jsfiddle link.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you reduce the entire thing to:

```
$('select').change(function (e) {
    $('.three').prop('disabled', ($('.one').val() == '2' || $('.two').val() == '3'));
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UEpQn/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that checks both `select`s (`.one` and `.two.`) and enables/disables the third `select`. Then you bind that function with the 'change' event of both `select`s.
Something like this:

```
var selectsChanged = function (e) {
    if (($('.one').val() == '2') || ($('.two').val() == '3')) {
        $('.three').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('.three').prop('disabled', false);
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    //$('.one').change(selectsChanged);
    //$('.two').change(selectsChanged);
    $('.one, .two').change(selectsChanged);
});
// Thx @ Bali Balo & Eran Medan for pointing out the shorter alternative
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wpAJE/)**.

Comment: `$('.one, .two').change(selectsChanged);` is shorter and less redundant.

Comment: I think you can narrow it down to  `$('.one, .two').change(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on({"change":function(event){
  if(($(this).is('.one') && $(this).val()==2) ||
     $(this).is('.two') && $(this).val()==3){
    $(this.form).find('.three').prop("disabled",true);
  }else{
    $(this.form).find('.three').prop("disabled",false);
  }
}},'.one, .two',null)
```